# Dynamic Chart Series Labels

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have some Visual Basic Code that creates a chart for each row.  It sets the series values using this code:

.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Ws.Name & "!R" & CurrRow & "C3:R" & CurrRow & "C8"

What I am struggling with is how do I set the series labels?  The series labels will always be the 1st row and be in the corresponding column.  I know this is much simplier than the code above, but I am stumped.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Ws.Range("C1:H1").Value in the .SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels Method.

Comment: These are Data Labels, not Series Names.

Comment: Yes, which is what it appears the OP was actually asking for.

Comment: The ability to use ranges for data labels was not available until Excel 2013; the OP could not have been using any version later than 2010 when he posted. Even in Excel 2013, you can't assign a range in the ApplyDataLabels method, you have to add it in another step. In earlier versions, you need to populate the text of each label independently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from your command for the Y Values, you want this:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & Ws.Name & "!R" & CurrRow & "C2"
```

which is the same row as the Y values, the column before the Y values start.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer interpreted the question as asking for the series name. If you want to use a range for the data labels, it's a bit trickier.

If you have Excel 2013, you can directly assign a range:

```
With .SeriesCollection(1)
  .ApplyDataLabels
  With .DataLabels
    .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField _
        msoChartFieldRange, "='" & Ws.Name & "'!R1C3:R1C8", 0
    .ShowRange = True
    .ShowValue = False
  End With
End With
```

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you have to step through the labels.

This assigns the static text of the cells to the labels:

```
Dim iPt As Long
Dim rLabels As Range

Set rLabels = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(1, 3), Ws.Cells(1, 8))

With .SeriesCollection(1)
  .ApplyDataLabels
  For iPt = 1 To .Points.Count
    .Points(iPt).DataLabel.Text = rLabels.Cells(iPt).Text
  Next
End With
```

This links each label to the corresponding cell, so the label reflects any changes in the cells:

```
Dim iPt As Long
Dim rLabels As Range

Set rLabels = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(1, 3), Ws.Cells(1, 8))

With .SeriesCollection(1)
  .ApplyDataLabels
  For iPt = 1 To .Points.Count
    .Points(iPt).DataLabel.Text = "=" & rLabels.Cells(iPt).Address(, , , True)
  Next
End With
```